# how to select nth result on command line without using mouse

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, shell, grep

I got this alias for searching for a file recursively and case insensitive

```
type fr
fr is aliased to `find . | grep -i'
```

and so let's say i'm searching for a file

```
fr nsstring+util
./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.d
./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.dia
./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.o
./SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.h
./SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.m
```

and i want to select the last file.. without having to leave the keybaord and highlighting it etc.. is there a shortcut for that on cli?

To be more specific.. the entire scenario is
- search for a file
- see retrieved results
- basically execute a command on one of them.. in this case I just want to run

```
vi SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.m
```

without leaving the keyboard

**Update:**

The idea is that this command must be done in two parts:

- fr filename and manually see the results returned.. there could be many results and the desired one could be in *any* one of the lines
- vi %result of above command% at a specific line

Comment: @vembutech i'm not sure i understand.. can you repeat the above point using my example?

Comment: I use M-x grep-find in emacs.  I don't know how to do that in vi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without leaving the keyboard, you can select specific lines with `sed`, and wrap the previous command within `$(...)`, like this:

```
vi "$(fr nsstring+util | sed -ne 3p)"
```

To select the last line, you can use `$` instead of a concrete number, but then you have to quote the `sed` command:

```
vi "$(fr nsstring+util | sed -ne '$p')"
```

For a more general purpose, you can define a function:

```
nvi() { n=$1; shift; vi "$(eval "$*" | sed -n ${n}p)"; }
```

Then, to edit the 5th line of the output of the previous command, you could do this:

```
fr nsstring+util
nvi 5 !!
```

Comment: that's close.. but what if i want to open `NSString+Util.h` instead? the result i want isn't guaranteed to be in the last line

Comment: i also modified my alias to get rid of some of the bloat.. so your `cut -d` won't be necessary.. but i'm still wondering about selecting which line

Comment: $ is the last line in sed. You can use a line number instead, for example 4p. Is that close enough?

Comment: it works.. but i wouldn't say it's usable.. it's def harder to type all that instead of just highlighting the line.. see my [answer](http://superuser.com/a/857000/234141)

Comment: See my update, hope this is more usable. In any case, it's more efficient to use `sed -n Np` construct than `head -N | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the idea is to create a function that can take arguments.. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/766570)

here are the functions:

```
function fr { find . | grep -in "$1"; }
function vifr { vi "`find . | head -$1 | tail -1`"; }
```

a sample usage is:

```
$ fr nsstring+util
9675:./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.d
9676:./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.dia
9677:./Build/Intermediates/SmartTaxi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartTaxi.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Util.o
10232:./SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.h
10233:./SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.m

$ vifr 10233
```

the last commands does the same as

```
vi ./SmartTaxi/Classes/Categories/NSString+Util.m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `dialog` then you can do this:

```
find . | grep -i "$1" | sed -e '/$/G' | xargs -d'\n' dialog --menu "text" 0 0 0 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | xargs vi
```

You could do something similar with `zenity` if you only have that and X output.